# Why is position attribute altering display: flex?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to implement a resizable table of content that has to have fixed position, however position: fixed is positioning .topic_body behind the .toc. If I delete the position attribute, I will get desired output, but on my actual website, the position attribute is very important. Is there any way to "workaround" this problem?

Here is a non working example (the position of toc is fixed):

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
    <div class="test">
        <div class="toc">
        </div>
        <div class="topic_body">
             <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .test {
            display: flex;
        }
        
        .topic_body {
            flex-grow: 1;
            background: lightblue;
        }
        
        .toc {
            resize: horizontal;
            overflow: auto;
            border: 1px solid black;
            margin-right: 12px !important;
            background-color: #f1f1f1;
            height: 82vh;
            width: 500px;
            position: fixed;
        }
    </style>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you explain how "*`position: fixed` is ruining everything...*"? Obviously that's the problem you're trying to address, but without an explanation of what the problem *is* we're effectively just guessing at what might be a solution. It's probably worth taking a look at "*[ask]*" and possibly taking the [tour].

Comment: It is working as you written the code. What is your expectation?

Comment: if you delete the position: fixed; you should see how it should actually work. But in this case position: fixed; is very important for me. @Shashank Gb

Comment: @dihime You need `.toc` and `.topic_body` be side by side but `.toc` should be horizontally resizable right?

Comment: that's right @Shashank Gb

Comment: @dihime Just try replacing `position: fixed` from `.toc` to `.test`

Comment: "*but on my actual website, the position attribute is very important"* - but obviously it is not working. So you need a fix, which might be completely something else, unless you explain why you need fixed positioning, we can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed;` takes an element out of the document flow (also out of your flex content), which can cause overlapping, since its position parameters only refer to the viewport/window, not to any other element.

You might want to use `position: absolute` instead, apply `position: relative` to its parent element to define it as the position anchor and use a `margin-top` on the `topic-body` element to avoid the overlap. Or use something entirely different...

Answer (score -1):

If you want fix position in scrolling, you need to use `position: sticky;`

[More Info at W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div.sticky {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #cae8ca;
  border: 2px solid #4CAF50;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Try to <b>scroll</b> inside this frame to understand how sticky positioning works.</p>

<div class="sticky">I am sticky!</div>

<div style="padding-bottom:2000px">
  <p>In this example, the sticky element sticks to the top of the page (top: 0), when you reach its scroll position.</p>
  <p>Scroll back up to remove the stickyness.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
  <p>Some text to enable scrolling.. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, illum definitiones no quo, maluisset concludaturque et eum, altera fabulas ut quo. Atqui causae gloriatur ius te, id agam omnis evertitur eum. Affert laboramus repudiandae nec et. Inciderint efficiantur his ad. Eum no molestiae voluptatibus.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```